# nodejs creating dns name for application

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

Hi I have node js application. I run it locally as :

`http.createServer(processRequest).listen(1337);`

To rich my application in browser I need to write: `localhost:1337/index.html`

So I have 2 questions:

1. If I want to rich my application as `www.myapp.dev/index.html` instead of `localhost:1337/index.html`, what I need to change in my code?
2. I bought domain `www.myserver.com`, what I need to put in my app in order to do it work in this domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to change `1337` to `80` (technically you don't **need** to do that, you could run an proxy on port 80 instead).
2. Nothing

Your app isn't paying attention to the Host header, so it doesn't matter what Host header the browser sends.

Outside the app you will need to configure your DNS to point the hostname at your IP address.

Comment: ok, but how to call my application as www.myapp.dev instead of localhost on local machine?

Comment: *configure your DNS to point the hostname at your IP address*